# Error: "'net' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Tags: windows-xp, command-line-interface, scripting, windows-service

Has anyone seen this error on an XP desktop machine before?

> 'net' is not recognized as an internal
>   or external command, operable program
>   or batch file.

It's being used in a 'net start iisadmin' script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like your 'path' environmental variable is getting stomped on somewhere. The fix is to do a direct call to it like has been suggested above.

Comment: Why would that happen? Name collision?

Comment: @Nikos A name collision would not give you the 'command not found' error message, it would give you a syntax error for invalid command-line operations. The PATH env-var has been zeroed or otherwise modified for reasons unknown.

Answer (score 6):

Try looking for a file called **net.exe** in C:\WINDOWS\system32\

If it is there then try using an explicit path to the file in your script.

E.g.:

`C:\WINDOWS\system32\net.exe start iisadmin`

Answer (score 1):

Yep, seen it more than once. Try using the full path and name to net.exe.